# How to create a jQuery slider with two ranges

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I would like to use a jQuery slider but with 2 ranges (4 marks)

Like 2 sliders together.

https://jqueryui.com/slider/#range

Is it supported by this plugin. Or is there a workaround to do that?

Comment: Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q5WEe/1/